# How to add Script in the Page <head></head> dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, scriptmanager

I use asp.net 4 and c#.

I have a Web User Control inside a Web From page.
When I include the Web User Control I would like also include programmatically some script within the  tags for the final generated page.

Any idea how to do it?
Maybe ScriptManager could help on this?

Please provide me a sample of code I'm pretty new at developing thanks for your time on this!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Peter's answer will add to the page, but not the head element. Take a look at this article:

http://weblogs.asp.net/johnkatsiotis/archive/2008/08/08/add-scripts-to-head-dynamically.aspx

It provides a nice clean way to add a script to the head element using an extension method.

Comment: I should mention that one of the crucial bits for adding anything to the head dynamically in server side code is adding runat="server" to your head element.

Answer (score 4):

I realize that this is an old question, but there is a much simpler way.

Try This:

```
Page.Header.Controls.Add(
    new LiteralControl(
        "<script>alert('Literal Added to <Head>.');</script>"
    )
);
```

If you want to add the script at a particular index of the `<head>` you can use

`AddAt(index, new LiteralControl(...))` where index 0 equals the top of the `<head>`

Also, joelmdev mentioned in a comment you need to add `runat="server"` in your head tag e.g. `<head id="head1" runat="server">`

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [RegisterClientScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btf44dc9.aspx) of the ClientScriptManager.

From MSDN:

```
...
ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

// Check to see if the client script is already registered.
if (!cs.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(csType, csName))
{
  StringBuilder csText = new StringBuilder();
  csText.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\"> function DoClick() {");
  csText.Append("Form1.Message.value='Text from client script.'} </");
  csText.Append("script>");
  cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(csType, csName, csText.ToString());
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks Peter I understand, I still have a problem using within a MasterPage, the wired thing is from a web form with no master page the script is working fine, if there is a mp i'm not able to add in the <head>... any idea how to fix it? thanks for your time on this.